# I cannot find module 'Graphics.Element'

Tags: elm

I am trying to play around with Elm (0.17) a little bit. But I can't get this simple example running:

```
import Graphics.Element exposing (..)

main =
  show "Hello!"
```

The following error is shown when running `elm reactor`:

> I cannot find module 'Graphics.Element'.
>
> Module 'Main' is trying to import it.
>
> Potential problems could be:
>
> - Misspelled the module name
> - Need to add a source directory or new dependency to elm-package.json

I did run `elm package install evancz/elm-graphics` and it was successfully. I also see it when opening localhost:8000 under the Dependencies Sidebar.

When looking at other examples they doing the import the same way.

What could cause the problem?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In version 0.17, The module name has changed to `Element` and you'll need to convert Graphics elements to Html now. Try changing your code to the following:

```elm
import Element exposing (..)

main =
  toHtml <| show "Hello!"
```

Comment: Although this compiles in version 0.17.1, it gives a runtime error : **Uncaught ReferenceError: Elm is not defined**  .  To avoid this I had to wrap with beginnerProgram : `main = beginnerProgram { model = () , view = \_ -> toHtml <| show "Hello!" , update = \_ _ -> ()}`

Answer (score 6):

According to the current [elm-lang.org/examples](http://elm-lang.org/examples/hello-html) hello-html is now written as

```
import Html exposing (text)

main =
  text "Hello!"
```